# Avoiding while loops

Tags: algorithm

This isn't strictly speaking a coding question as I'm in charge of a spreadsheet rather than code, but the same principles apply.

I'm trying to create a piece of my spreadsheet that is an "average predictor". As an example: say a batsman has an average of 24 from 40 innings (in other words, has scored 960 runs). If he consistently performs at an average of 40 runs per innings from here on in, how many innings will it take for him to raise his career average to 30?

It's pretty easy to work this example out by hand, and just as easy to solve the general problem with a while loop. However, as mentioned, I can't use loops. Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Use algebra to develop a general formula, then write code that corresponds to the formula.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about solving a mathematical problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a loop for this purpose. You can solve it by using the following formula ([moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average)):

```
(current_avg * current_innings + avg * x)/(current_innings + x) = goal_avg
```

You have to solve the equation for `x`.

Your example calculated on Wolfram Alpha:

Input: `(24 * 40 + 40 * x)/(40 + x) = 30 solve x`
Result: `x=24`

[Link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2824%20*%2040%20%2B%2040%20*%20x%29%2F%2840%20%2B%20x%29%20%3D%2030%20solve%20x)

Answer (score 0):

As recommended by @StriplingWarrior in a comment on the question, write out the general equation, solve it algebraically, and use the resulting formula in your spreadsheet. The raw equation is given in the prior answer by @trylimits. I'm using slightly different identifiers to bring out the symmetry of the problem:

```
(old_avg * old_innings + new_avg * new_innings)/(old_innings + new_innings) 
              = goal_avg
old_avg * old_innings + new_avg * new_innings 
              = goal_avg * (old_innings + new_innings)
old_avg * old_innings + new_avg * new_innings 
              = goal_avg * old_innings + goal_avg * new_innings
new_avg * new_innings - goal_avg *  new_innings
              = goal_avg * old_innings - old_avg * old_innings
new_innings * (new_avg - goal_avg) = old_innings * (goal_avg - old_avg)
```

If `new_avg - goal_avg` is zero there is no solution unless `goal_avg - old_avg` is also zero, in which case no change is required and `new_innings` can be zero. If `new_avg - goal_avg` is non-zero:

```
new_innings = old_innings * (goal_avg - old_avg) / (new_avg - goal_avg)
```

The right hand side of this equation is a formula you could put in a spreadsheet.

The values from the example are:

```
old_avg = 24
old_innings = 40
new_avg = 40
goal_avg = 30

new_innings = 40 * (30 - 24) / (40 - 30)
            = 240 / 10 
            = 24
```